# Is parameter's default value still valid in sub class?

Tags: scala, overriding, default-arguments

I have following code snippet,

```
trait DefaultValueInheritance {
  def print(str: String = "abc")
}

class MyDefaultValueInheritance extends DefaultValueInheritance {
  //Didn't provide default value in the sub class
  override  def print(str: String): Unit = {
    println(str)
  }
}

object MyDefaultValueInheritance {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = new MyDefaultValueInheritance
    a.print()
  }
}
```

In the trait, `DefaultValueInheritance`, I define a method `print`, with default value for the argument: `str`.

In the sub class, when I override the `print` method, I didn't provide the default value for the `str` parameter,

I am still able to call `a.print()`, looks the default value still valid, I don't know why, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, default parameters are inherited automatically by subclasses. In invoking `a.print()`, `"abc"` is passed as the `str` parameter.

See section on overriding: https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/named-and-default-arguments.html

Answer (score 4):

Spec says it, but it's in section 5.1.4 Overriding, not the section on Default Args 4.6.1:

> An overriding method inherits all default arguments from the
>   definition in the superclass. By specifying default arguments in the
>   overriding method it is possible to add new defaults (if the
>   corresponding parameter in the superclass does not have a default) or
>   to override the defaults of the superclass (otherwise).

Plus there are restrictions on overloads; I find it all confusing. I'd like to see an example where overriding a default arg solves a problem (as opposed to introducing a headache).

Answer (score 4):

By using `scalac -Xprint:4`, you can find the trick

Comment: Wow I didn't think anyone used the numbers, +1!